# With Reactive Extensions (RX) how to solve compile error "cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.IObserver"

Tags: c#, system.reactive

When using `IObservable`, this line will not compile:

```
var x = receiver.Updates().Subscribe(OnNewMessage);
```

I get this error:

```
Error   3   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.IObserver<IMyClass>'
```

And this error:

```
Error   2   The best overloaded method match for 'System.IObservable<IMyClass>.Subscribe(System.IObserver<IMyClass>)' has some invalid arguments
```

The source code uses `IObservable`.

Comment: This is a bad example of http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: @SonerGönül Indeed, I'm torn as to whether the question is ok, but the answer is calling out one of the compiler's most common error messages as "unhelpful" when it blatantly tells you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: Could the people who voted this down please explain why? This question/answer pair is extremely useful to anyone (including myself)  who wants to google this error in the context of IObservable to find a potential solution. There were no other google results for this compiler error. What is your problem, again?

Comment: I didn't vote it down, but I did provide a (hopefully!) proper explanation of the error and a full resolution, which also includes a using statement for the System namespace.

Comment: @James Really nice answer, I've marked it as the official one. Thanks!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.IObserver<IMyClass>'
```

is quite clear provided you understand the terminology. It is raised because the .NET Framework Base Class Library `System.IObservable<T>` interface defines a single method with the signature:

```
IDisposable Subscribe(System.IObserver<T>)
```

and you are passing a method group. A method group is quite literally what it says, a group of methods. In particular, in this case it is the group of methods in scope with the name `OnNewMessage`. It is specified by passing a method name without parentheses. Using a method group is a shorthand that causes the compiler to use method overload resolution to find a method that can be converted to a typed delegate. Of course, no such method can exist for a type of `System.IObserver<T>` as it is not a typed delegate.

This error is crops up a lot when forgetting to include an assembly that contains a desired extension method and/or forgetting to include the `using` statement for the required namespace of that extension method.

In this case the intention was clearly to satisfy an extension method defined by the Reactive Extensions framework - Rx defines a number of extension methods on `IObservable<T>` that are a convenient shorthand for building an *observer* - that is a implementation of the `System.IObserver<T>` interface -  and subscribing it to an observable in one go. The observer interface defines the following three methods:

```
void OnNext(T value);
void OnError<T>(Exception error);
void OnCompleted();
```

The various extension methods provided by Rx are defined in [System.Reactive.Core](http://rx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Rx.NET/Source/System.Reactive.Core/Observable.Extensions.cs) and build an `Observer` implementation using supplied `Action`s in various combinations to fulfill the contract above. I've linked to the actual definition of these in the source of Rx. The simplest is the one that accepts an `OnNext` handler and provides a default implementation for the `OnError` and `OnCompleted` methods. It looks like this:

```
public static IDisposable Subscribe<T>(
    this IObservable<T> source, Action<T> onNext);
```

These extension methods are defined in the `System` namespace, so in addition to referencing the `System.Reactive.Core` assembly (in nuget packet `Rx-Core`, although most users will want at least the additional libraries provided by `Rx-Main`) you must also have a `using System;` declaration in your source file.

The second error:

```
The best overloaded method match for     
'System.IObservable<IMyClass>.Subscribe(System.IObserver<IMyClass>)'
has some invalid arguments.
```

is also in the same vein, confirming that best method the compiler could find (probably the only method of supplied method group in this case) was not convertible to the required type of the single `IObserver<T>` argument to the `Subscribe` method.

Comment: Just ran into this where the root cause was despite adding the System.Reactive 3.1.1 nuget packages, the project references weren't updated properly. Once I uninstalled and reinstalled the packages the references were corrected and the error went away. The blurb about missing extension methods really helped!

Comment: I cannot believe `using System;` is what I needed.
@james-world I appreciate the explanation and not just as "short-cut" to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is a rather unhelpful error.

If you are using RX and IObservable, then the solution is to add the following assemblies to your project:

```
System.Reactive.Core.dll
System.Reactive.Interfaces.dll
System.Reactive.Linq.dll
System.Reactive.PlatformServices.dll
```

Alternatively, you can use [NuGet to add Reactive Extensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rx-Main/) to your project.

Once you add these assemblies, if you are using ReSharper,  then it will helpfully offer to add the correct "using" directives.

Comment: That's the solution if you know the overload for a lambda exists and are trying to target that, otherwise the error is immediately **very** helpful... calling it "unhelpful" is because *you* know you are after that Rx overload that is "around here somewhere", the compiler hasn't got a blind clue what you're up to, all it knows is you've done something illegal and it's spotted it. That said, Roslyn is now open source so I leave it to you to write the NuGet package reflection search compiler add-on that tries to find something that'll make your code valid for you...

Comment: @Adam This error message is only helpful, from your point of view,  because you are an expert. Google "hindsight bias", and spare a thought for anyone with less than 10 years of programming experience.

Comment: I actually have less than 10 years experience. I realise that the entire example is context specific, but the compiler message is not as specific and I disagree with your first sentence. Also, "usefulness" is subjective, most people using Rx probably have the references but are instead missing using directives, which your answer doesn't detail anything about.

Comment: @Adam You are correct that I didn't mention the using directives, I have updated my answer to include this.